# How to Re-Enable Zoom on iPhone with Javascript (Bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, bookmarklet

I'm trying to code up a bookmarklet I can use on my iPhone to re-enable zoom on sites that have disabled it.

So far I found this [bookmarklet](https://gist.github.com/beastaugh/725354) someone already made with this javascript:

```
(function() {
    var metaElements = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
        i            = metaElements.length,
        el;

    while (i--) {
        el = metaElements[i];
        if (el.name.toLowerCase() == 'viewport') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
})();
```

and I found [a page](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/mobile-viewport.php) to test it out on.

But it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it on my iphone.

Any ideas what it needs to work?  Is there something here not compatible with Safari?

Comment: Anything in the Debug Console of Safari?

Comment: It doesn't look like I can access the debug console on the latest iphone os.  And I don't have a mac to connect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently removing the viewport meta tag doesn't work, rather it has to be changed. 
This should re-enable zoom:

```
(function() {
   var metaElements = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
    i            = metaElements.length,
    el;

   while (i--) {
      el = metaElements[i];
      if (el.name.toLowerCase() == 'viewport') {
        el.content = "user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=100";
      }
   }
})();
```

and as a bookmarklet: `javascript:(function(){var e=document.getElementsByTagName("meta"),t=e.length,n;while(t--){n=e[t];if (n.name.toLowerCase()=="viewport"){n.content="user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=100;";}}})();`

**WARNING:** Stackoverflow might be adding invisible characters to that bookmarklet, if it doesn't work try removing them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now.  I guess you could also just set the content to ""?

Comment: So trying this on the test page, I can now zoom in, but when I take my fingers off the screen it puts the zoom level back to where it was. Maybe the test page was already at some iphone maximum zoom level?)

Comment: Trying this: `javascript:(function(){var b=document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),c=b.length,a;while(c--){a=b[c];if(a.name.toLowerCase()=='viewport'){a.content='user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=100'}}})();`

Comment: results, that seems to have no effect at all.  Back to no zooming.  I wonder what's going on?

Comment: Hmm, still no luck for me.  I copied from your last comment.

Comment: Ok ignore my comment about semicolons the spec actually says to use commas. There was a formatting issue w/ the bookmarklet. Try this: `javascript:(function(){var e=document.getElementsByTagName("meta"),t=e.length,n;while(t--){n=e[t];if(n.name.toLowerCase()=="viewport"){n.content="user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=100;"}}})()`

Comment: Okay this is stupid: THE CODE WORKS EITHER WAY (with uri encode AND without) - it just get screwed up when you copy and paste it from here - the linebreaks get added to the code. LMAO! Just make sure to format it properly and remove the extra characters.

Comment: Thanks!  It works for me now.  I updated your answer.  Feel free to fix it if I messed it up.  Thanks again!